# Compute Angle of line in conventional bearing using ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, point, line, angles

I am trying to compute angle between two lines (line segment) using ESRI (ArcGIS, JS) in conventional bearing (Eg: N29'E)

I am using Add Toolbar to draw a line segment where point A is a fixed point (already drawn) and when the user is hovering over the map looking for point B, it should display projected angle.

Has anybody tried anything like this before or any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For anyone needing this:

```
function computeAngle(pointA, pointB){
                var dLon = (pointB.x - pointA.x) * Math.PI / 180;
                var lat1 = pointA.y * Math.PI / 180;
                var lat2 = pointB.y * Math.PI / 180;
                var y = Math.sin(dLon) * Math.cos(lat2);
                var x = Math.cos(lat1)*Math.sin(lat2) - Math.sin(lat1)*Math.cos(lat2)*Math.cos(dLon);
                var bearing = Math.atan2(y, x)  * 180 / Math.PI;
                bearing = ((bearing + 360) % 360).toFixed(1); //Converting -ve to +ve (0-360)
                if(bearing >= 0 && bearing < 90){
                    return 'N' + (bearing != 0  ? bearing + 'E' : '');
                }
                if(bearing >= 90 && bearing < 180){
                    return (bearing != 90  ? 'S' + (180 - bearing).toFixed(1) : '') + 'E';
                }
                if(bearing >= 180 && bearing < 270){
                    return 'S' + (bearing != 180  ? (bearing - 180).toFixed(1) + 'W' : '');
                }
                if(bearing >= 270){
                    return (bearing != 270  ? 'N' + (360 - bearing).toFixed(1) : '') + 'W';
                }
                return 'N';
}
```

References:

http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

http://www.mathsteacher.com.au/year7/ch08_angles/07_bear/bearing.htm

Answer (score 4):

**Bearing Distance To Line (Data Management)**

> Creates a new feature class containing geodetic line features
>   constructed based on the values in an x-coordinate field, y-coordinate
>   field, bearing field, and distance field of a table.

[image]

**bearing_units
(Optional)**

> The units of the values in the Bearing Field.
>
> ```
> DEGREES —Values in decimal degrees; this is the default.
> MILS —Values in mils.
> RADS —Values in radians.
> GRADS —Values in gradians.
> ```

source:
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0017000000ts000000

Comment: Thanks!! Anything for Javascript?

Comment: You need to use ArcGIS Server Geo-processing and the Javascript API http://help.arcgis.com/EN/WEBAPI/JAVASCRIPT/ARCGIS/help/jshelp_start.htm#jshelp/intro_gp_overview.htm