# Getting First and Last Point coordinates of Polyline with Field Calculator in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, field-calculator, coordinates, line

I'm trying to get the First Point coordinates (x,y) and Final Point coordinates (x2,y2) from a polyline in ArcGIS 10 with the Field calculator.

I've added 4 (double) fields like StartX,StartY,EndX and EndY,I tried with:

```
"!Shape!.positionAlongLine(0.0,True).firstPoint.X"
"!Shape!.positionAlongLine(0.0,True).firstPoint.Y"
"!Shape!.positionAlongLine(1.0,True).firstPoint.X"
"!Shape!.positionAlongLine(1.0,True).firstPoint.Y"
```

But no luck. **The error: "The row contains a bad value".**

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks to @radouxju for your answer because it was what I was looking for!!, **but NOW I don't know What's happening with my ArcGIS10.** Let's see:

I could compute all these statements (4), to every field:

- "!Shape!.lastPoint.X"
- "!Shape!.lastPoint.Y"...

But, after that I checked for errors and I found this! That there are times that the ArcGIS field calculator doesn't compute well. In the example, the yellow one, it's 16 meter long, but its coordinates are the same, but the the next polyline is well computed... What's happening?

[image: Error with ArcGIS10]

Comment: For greater understanding, the question that triggered this one is http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/99669/how-to-compute-and-fill-one-way-field-in-a-street-shapefile-according-spacial-po#comment138239_99669

Answer (score 6):

you do not need "positionalongline" in your case. A simple snippets would be:

```
"!Shape!.firstPoint.X"
```

similarly, you can use

```
"!Shape!.lastPoint.Y"
```

However, this should have worked. So the first thing to do is to use Repair Geometry to remove problematic rows, or use a code block to handle issues in your features

```
def robustFX(shp):
    if (shp and (shp.length > 0)):
        return str(shp.FirstPoint.X)
    else:
        return "no data"
```

Comment: Thanks @radouxju !!it works with: "!Shape!.firstPoint.X" in a String field. ;)

Comment: QUESTION edited, found some troubles  :(  @radouxju

Comment: maybe it is a naive question, but how long is your line when you measure it on the screen ?

Comment: I measured myself again and the same as shown in "Shape_Lenght"

Comment: this is really strange, could you please try with "!Shape!.positionAlongLine(0.5,True).firstPoint.Y". Could you also start an edit session and check the from and to coordiantes of this strange line.